# BackHandler does not close React Native app

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to trigger the Back button on Android to close the application, but it just doesn't work.
On JS part, I can see this `BackHandler.exitApp()` being executed:

```javascript
const handleHardwareBack = navigation => () => {
    // Back performs pop, unless we're to main screen [0,0]
    if (navigation.state.index === 0 || navigation.state.index === 2) {
        BackHandler.exitApp();
        return false;
    }
    return navigation.goBack(null);
};
```

On the android side, I can see this portion being executed:

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

But since there's always a mReactInstanceManager, `super.onBackPressed();` never gets called (which is the one who closes the app).

What am I missing? How should/can I see if I'm

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';

export default class RoomType extends Component {
     _didFocusSubscription;
     _willBlurSubscription;
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this._didFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus',payload =>
            BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid)
         ); 
     }
  }
componentDidMount() {
        this._willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', payload =>
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid)
        );
 }
componentWillUnmount() {
        this._didFocusSubscription && this._didFocusSubscription.remove();
        this._willBlurSubscription && this._willBlurSubscription.remove();
    }
onBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
    //code when you press the back button
    // Back performs pop, unless we're to main screen [0,0]
    if (navigation.state.index === 0 || navigation.state.index === 2) {
        BackHandler.exitApp();
        return true;
    }
 };
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? Is there any error? Does it get to onBackButtonPressAndroid()?

Comment: No error is being displayed. The Back button is being pressed and I can debug it on both ends (JS and Java) and see that `BackHandler.exitApp();` is being executed, and right after that, the Java side is executing `mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();`. If I alter my condition to always execute `super.onBackPressed();` instead, the app is actually closed. :) But from ANY screen in the navigator stack, not only when `BackHandler.exitApp();` is called